# Query in many to many relationship - mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have the following tables, table A and table B

**Table A (users)**

```
userid    name
--------------------
1         Sam
2         David
```

**Table B (hobbylist)**

```
hobbyid   hobby
--------------------
1         singing
2         drawing
```

---

I have a bridge table (many to many relationship)

**Table C (user_hobby)**

```
userid    hobbyid
--------------------
1         1
2         2
1         2
```

I want to query for a condition where I want to know which user has a hobby equal to "drawing" (hobbyid 2) but not "singing" (hobbyid 1). **How can I achieve this without sub-query**?

I tried with the following query

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM hobbylist 
     JOIN user_hobby AS uh 
       ON hobbylist.hobbyid = uh.hobbyid
     JOIN users AS us 
       ON us.userid = uh.userid
WHERE hobby = "drawing" 
  AND hobby <> "singing"
```

I am still getting both users as a result of the above query. It should have shown only user = David.

**How can I achieve this without using sub-query**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can `Group by` on the userid and name. This will aggregate the results into single row for a particular user.
- Now, we can use `Having` with `Sum()` to filter out the cases. `Sum(hobby = 'drawing')` will be positive for users having drawing as hobby. `Sum(hobby = 'singing')` will be zero for users not having singing as a hobby at all.

Try the following:

```
SELECT us.userid,
       us.name
FROM   hobbylist
       JOIN user_hobby AS uh
         ON hobbylist.hobbyid = uh.hobbyid
       JOIN users AS us
         ON us.userid = uh.userid
GROUP  BY us.userid,
          us.name
HAVING Sum(hobby = 'drawing')
       AND Sum(hobby = 'singing') = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select uh.userid
from user_hobby uh join
     hobby h
     on h.hobbyid = uh.hobbyid
where h.hobby in ('drawing', 'singing')
group by uh.userid
having min(h.hobby) = max(h.hobby) and min(h.hobby) = 'drawing';
```

Note that to get the `userid`, you don't need the users table.

Answer (score 0):

Try a innerjoin like:

```
select * from hobbylist, user_hobby, users where users.userid = user_hobby.userid and hobbylist.hobbyid = user_hobby.hobbyid and hobbylist.hobby = "drawing" and hobbylist.hobby <> "singing"
```